# Are there restrictions/problems with naming macros in C?

Tags: c, macros, naming

I want to have functions which can have optional arguments. Of course this cannot be done with C, but it is possible with some macro magic:

```c
#define _macroWith1Arg(_0, _1, macroName, ...)          _ ## macroName
#define _macroWith2Args(_0, _1, _2, macroName, ...)     _ ## macroName
#define _macroWith3Args(_0, _1, _2, _3, macroName, ...) _ ## macroName

#define macroWith1Arg(macroName, ...)               _macroWith1Arg(_0, __VA_ARGS__, macroName ## _1, macroName ## _0)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define macroWith2Args(macroName, ...)              _macroWith2Args(_0, __VA_ARGS__, macroName ## _2, macroName ## _1, macroName ## _0)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define macroWith3Args(macroName, ...)              _macroWith3Args(_0, __VA_ARGS__, macroName ## _3, macroName ## _2, macroName ## _1, macroName ## _0)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define _sum_1(_1)      (_1)
#define _sum_2(_1, _2)  (_1) + (_2)
#define sum(...)        macroWith2Args(sum, __VA_ARGS__)

fprintf(stderr, "%d ", sum(1)); // Prints 1
fprintf(stderr, "%d ", sum(1, 2)); // Prints 3
```

I like the way it looks: it looks like a normal function with optional arguments. But the drawback of this is you can't have a function pointer to a macro like `sum`. So I heard you should capitalize the name to mark it explicit as a macro (like "SUM") to avoid confusion.

Now I my question is: is this naming convention really necessary, I mean standard C does it with `errno` for example (at least on my platform)? I think most IDEs can identify macros and highlight them as such. I would really like to hear your opinion on this.

**EDIT**:

I found a way to achieve that you can take a function pointer:

```c
int my_sum(int, int);
#define _sum_1(_1)     my_sum(_1, 0)
#define _sum_2(_1, _2) my_sum(_1, _2)
#define sum(...)       macroWith2Args(sum, __VA_ARGS__)
int (*sum)(int, int) = my_sum;

// Use it as a "function":
fprintf(stderr, "%d ", sum(1, 2)); // Prints 3
// Take a function pointer:
int (*sumptr)(int, int) = sum;
fprintf(stderr, "%d ", sumptr(1, 0)); // Prints 1
```

Comment: I hate the way it looks. It looks like a normal function, except such a function cannot exist. So even if you know C, you don't know this weird language that looks like C yet cannot possibly *be* C, so you have to spend time learning some werd project-specific dialect. So, from a maintenance/communications perspective, code like this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: "*I want to have functions which can have optional arguments. Of course this cannot be done with C ...*" There **is** the possibility to use variadic functions.

Comment: And yes, by convention macros in C are CAPITALISED. So at least everybody seeing such is prepared to wade/fight through what *unwind* mentions in his comment.

Comment: of course C allows variable length parameters. did you use `printf` before? it's a good example.

Comment: FYI, the C specification doesn't say *how* `errno` is defined or declared, as a macro or a variable, only that is have to be an lvalue.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: nitpicking: It is a macro. C11 (n1570) 7.5 p1/p2 _The header `<errno.h>` defines several macros [...]. The macros are [...] `errno` which expands to a modifiable lvalue [...]_

Comment: A function can be written to accept a variable number of argument.  For instance void myFunction( argCount, ... );  This: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html explains the details. (see my answer below)

Comment: @alk These are not optional arguments.

Comment: @user2005038: "*These ...*" Which?

Comment: @alk For example: `printf("%d", 10);` `10` is in this case not optional. Optional arguments are not variadic arguments.

Comment: I disagree. "Optional" arguments are (can be implmented using) variadic arguments, variadic arguments do not necessarily need to be optional.

Comment: I know that they can be implemented this way but its still not the same.

Comment: is <stdio.h> mainstream enough for you?  getc() is a macro.

Answer (score 4):

In C (the preprocessor is part of it) you can do even more than you are suggesting in your edit: macros and functions can have the same name. Whereas this is rarely done in application code, the C library itself can have that. Here standard functions can be implemeted as macros, but a symbol with the same name must also be provided.

So the standard itself doesn't stick to the rule that macro names should be all caps.

I think that if you are careful in your implementation such that

- calling the macro with a full set of parameters just is the identity in the preprocessor phase
- a valid function declaration is provided with the same name

then there should be no problem in using a lowercase identifier.

By that you ensure that

- repeating the prototype for your function is still a valid operation
- taking a function pointer can be done without problems

and in all your implementation is behaving **as if** your macro where a function.

BTW, the code that you posted is not standard conforming. Indentifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in file scope. This is not a convention but imperative.

Comment: ” Indentifiers starting with an underscore are reserved in file scope” what does this mean exactly?

Comment: In short that you shouldn't use them. Your compiler implementation is free to use such names for internal purposes. If you use them for your own symbols, they may clash with these internal names. This might not happen today on the platform you have, but some time later when you try to port your code to a new platform or upgrade your compiler to a newer version.

Comment: @JensGustedt And when I'm using prefixes? like `__mylib_var`

Comment: they still start with an underscore, no? Or use `mylib_var_something`, that would be fine. Also be careful with multiple underscores in a row, these are reserved by C++ for their name mangling schemes. So better not have that either.

Comment: @JensGustedt I cant understand this, why should the standard name something with my prefix on it? Like `__mySpecialPrefix_var` ?

Comment: This is certainly unlikely, but still you don't know what might be happening. If you have a function `mylib_func` your platform may even produce a linkersymbol, derived function, whatever, that is just prefixed by `_`. So the platform may produce names from the names that yoy provide and mangle them in some way. Stay on the safe side and just don't use reserved names.

Comment: @JensGustedt Okay, but can I at least name my variable like this: `mylib__var`? Heard that is forbidden too... but I cant find any reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

Naming conventions generally aren't *necessary*. They exist to communicate information to other programmers (including yourself a few weeks/months in the future). When another programmer sees

```
sum(a, b, c, d);
```

They will immediately think that it's a normal function that takes 4 parameters. However, if they see

```
SUM(a, b, c, d);
```

Then they will know it's a macro (assuming they are familiar with C naming conventions). After all, you're not always going to be viewing files in an IDE that knows about what macros and functions you've defined. People will see your code in diff tools and in text editors. They will generally expect macros to be in all caps and symbols that aren't in all caps to be things other than macros.

Answer (score 2):

convention works less in C. since C has fewer tools and compiler does less work, programmers have to be flexible to achieve some purpose. say the convention of macros is uppercase + underscore, but if you want to make people think some macros are functions, it's better for you to not follow this convention. in fact, some libraries fake a field in struct by not following this convention.

you mentioned `errno`. it's a good example. it's essentially a macro(glibc), returning a left value, so you can write `errno = 0;`. so in this way, library provider made you think `errno` was a global variable(this used to be what i thought it was too.), which is not. C programmers tend to be flexible and play some reasonable tricks. it's not the same as Java or C# this kind of enterprise oriented languages, which require programmers to strictly follow conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
// notice that the handling of a variable argument list
// is simple, built into C, and does not require a bunch of
// home grown macros.

// this function will take the number of values to average
// followed by all of the numbers to average

double average ( int num, ... )
{
    va_list arguments;                // A place to store the list of arguments
    double sum = 0;

    va_start ( arguments, num );  // Initializing arguments to store all values after num
    for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ )   // Loop until all numbers are added
    {
        sum += va_arg ( arguments, double ); // Adds the next value in argument list to sum.
    }
    va_end ( arguments );                  // Cleans up the list

    return sum / num;                      // Returns the average
}
```

Comment: I disagree that using variadric functions helps making things cleaner or even safer here.  If you misuse the OP's macros, you'll get a (potentially hard to understand) compiler error.  If you pass the wrong argument count to a variadric function, the compiler will be happy but you'll invoke undefined behavior at some later time.  Compiler makers have added special support for `printf` so it is comparatively safe, but other variadric functions are not.